# UUIDField in Django (error:operator does not exist: integer = uuid)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, uuid

i want to use uuid field as my id (primary key) but there is something wrong with it and i can't fix it ...

this is my model

```
class Course(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses/images')
    intro_video = models.FileField(upload_to='courses/videos')
    free = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

when i try to add a new course it gave's me this error

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/courses/course/add/
operator does not exist: integer = uuid
LINE 1: ..., "created_at" = NULL WHERE "courses_course"."id" = 'a130811...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value: operator does not exist: integer = uuid
```

my database is postgresql

please help me.

Comment: what django version do you have?

Comment: its 2.2.5 @Horatiu Jeflea

Comment: can you paste the code in which you are creating a new Course?

Comment: i dont know if i understand you right, but use django admin to add a new course @Horatiu Jeflea

Comment: got it now. But if you try to create a new Course from code, does it work? Either Course.objects.create or course.save()

Comment: it gave's the same error as before just in the terminal: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = uuid
LINE 1: ..., "created_at" = NULL WHERE "courses_course"."id" = '95483b8...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

@Horatiu Jeflea

Comment: can you do a `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: yes @Horatiu Jeflea

Comment: I mean, run the command, restart the server and check the code again

Comment: sorry, this one `python manage.py makemigrations courses` and then the `migrate` one

Comment: yes i did them all @Horatiu Jeflea

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
id=models.CharField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, max_length=36)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find another "simpliest" solution for this issue if you wanna use uuid field as "ID" you need to start with this field  as id befroe the first migration the cast missing part is because you id field dont make the change the propper way to an uuidField