# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type uuid to integer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku

I tried to upload my web to Heroku server and stuck at this ploblem

my error when I try to migrate my database

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type uuid to integer
LINE 1: ...ict_word" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE integer USING "id"::integer
                                                              ^
```

models.py

```
class Word(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    esearch = models.TextField()
    eentry = models.TextField()
    tentry = models.TextField()
    ecat = models.TextField()
    ethai = models.TextField(null=True)
    esyn = models.TextField(null=True)
    eant = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.eentry

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('word-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

does anybody know how to fix it

Answer (score 30):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342760/10746224):

> "A better approach is usually to add a uuid column, then fix up any foreign key references to point to it, and finally drop the original column."

So, to handle this in django, do the following:

**1)** revert migrations to a working graph

**2)** add **`temp_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)`** to your model, then run **`makemigrations`**

**3)** * add **`primary_key=True`** to the **`temp_id`** field, then run **`makemigrations`** again

**4)** rename the field to **`id`** (or to whatever you want), then run **`makemigrations`** a third time

**5)** push the migrations to the database via **`python3 manage.py migrate`**

*This example assumes you don't have data in the model you are changing.  If you do, you will have to add a **[`custom migration`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/writing-migrations/)** in **step 3**.

**Note** that this was tested using `django 3.1` and `postgres`; **YMMV**

Comment: Nice answer! I was having the same problem and your answer helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @AndressaCabistani You're welcome, glad to help

Comment: didn't worked for me, got errors at stage 3, saying it can't create another Primary key.

Answer (score 3):

After Hours, I Solved the Problem
With an really easy and simple way
According to this Post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69315948/9272467

**Just Delete all your migrations files in the migration directory**
Since converting the BigInt to UUID is the issue, just don't make BigInt in the first place, it won't have any issue to create it UUID ;)

Comment: this solution worked. and after doing so the migration worked but the database of mine had some old data of non UUID types. so had to clean the DB

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't have any references** to target table (or they can be dropped without pain), there is **a bit easier approach**, than described by @LordElrond:

1. Add `id = UUIDField(...)`
2. Run `makemigrations`
3. Open created migration and manually change

   ```
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name="mymodel",
        name="id",
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
    ),
   ```

   to

   ```
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name="mymodel",
        name="id",
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name="mymodel",
        name="id",
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
    ),
   ```

I guess, django could be doing it internally if no references to target table detected?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the default to **UUID** generator.

**example**:

```
id=models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,unique=True)
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when trying to use `uuid` as `id` on my djago model (django 3.2) with postgres.

I solved it by adding "`max_length=36`" – which will limit the length of a field.

Related question and answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60205812/uuidfield-in-django-erroroperator-does-not-exist-integer-uuid)

Comment: Didn't solved the issue for me but this page helped me a lot! so Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps if you DON'T have important data in the database.

First, set the field as a `CharField` and run `./manage.py makemigrations`.

```
id = CharField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Then update the `CharField` to `UUIDField` and run `./manage.py makemigrations`

```
id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Finally, run `./manage.py migrate`. Working on Django 4.2

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by simply manually changing the type of the id column in the table by replacing in with bigint
I hope it will be useful to whom this topic has touched.