# Django: How to fix UUID ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am using Python 3.8 and Django 3.0.

Models.py

```
class CustomeUser(AbstractUser):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
...

class ActivationCode(models.Model):
Code = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, unique=True)
ForUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

Code:

```
jj = {'app_id': '100',
 'color': 'blue',
 'os_type': 'MacOS',
 'time': '1596397345',
 'regKey': 'dJbeetbQ',
 'os_version': '10.15.6',
 'place_id': '20190228-3',
 'version': '2.0.0.8',
 'guid': '10614ba9b54f909a715ed518cc39741811369a11',
 'randomString': '3808651424'}

regKey = jj["regKey"]
record = ActivationCode.objects.get(Code=regKey)
```

will get exception when regKey matches a user record. If the ForUser field is null, it will go through.

What's the problem here?

Full trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-59-b3b355ae1522>", line 1, in <module>
    ActivationCode.objects.get(Code=regKey)
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 74, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1088, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\operations.py", line 270, in convert_uuidfield_value
    value = uuid.UUID(value)
  File "C:\Users\Ken\anaconda3\lib\uuid.py", line 160, in __init__
    raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
```

Comment: Have you imported the module? `import uuid`

Comment: Can you post the full traceback

Comment: @Kaushal yes, I did.

Comment: Do you have some bad data in the `ForUser_id` column? This error is probably caused by a value in that column that is not a valid UUID

Comment: I have some records that they are null. But no bad data.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of this error is simply arising from the fact that you have a `non-UUID` value in `ForUser_id`  column.

As you stated in the comments

> I have some records that they are null. But no bad data.

It seems to me as though `null` is what's causing this error. It is also not recommended for a `UUIDField` to use `null` values, instead use an empty string value conventions. The blog on [Using the null and blank field options](https://jodyboucher.com/blog/django-howto-null-blank-field-options) will be worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out what's wrong.

The problem was caused by some of the user records I updated in MySQL server using UUID(). but the UUID() in MYSQL is 36bytes and the UUID field in Django is 32 bytes.

now I updated the id again with id = UUID().Replace('-',''), then the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when I deleted all my old schema migrations and regenerated the migrations to fix [django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type uuid to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464113/django-db-utils-programmingerror-cannot-cast-type-uuid-to-integer). after fixing it when I tried to check my API/Admin i got the error. and later I figured out that as I didn't change the database values, so the old BigInt ID data now is in the UUID field and causing the error! so have to remove the old faulty data from the database column to get rid of this.