# Error in set UUID field as Primary Key in PostgreSQL and Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I decided to use `UUID` instead of default Django's Primary Key. Based on the the Django docs:

```
class Student(TimeStampModel):
    ...

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

When I migrate I will get the error down below:

**django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bigint to uuid
LINE 1: ...students_student" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid**

I checked the schema with `DBeaver`. the `id` saved as `bigserial`

Comment: please read this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464113/django-db-utils-programmingerror-cannot-cast-type-uuid-to-integer

Comment: @erfanmorsali Thanks. It did work :)

Comment: @MarcCompte Thanks :)