Cannot cast type bigint to UUID in Django migration when migrating from SQLite to PostgreSQL
I'm encountering an issue while migrating my Django project from SQLite to PostgreSQL. I had previously set the id field to UUID in SQLite, but now when applying the migration in PostgreSQL, I receive the following error:
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bigint to uuid
LINE 1: ...ompany_company" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid
^
my models
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Job(models.Model):
    BEGINNER = 'Beginner'
    MID = 'Mid'
    EXPERT = 'Expert'

    LEVEL_CHOICES = [
        (BEGINNER, 'Beginner'),
        (MID, 'Mid'),
        (EXPERT, 'Expert'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

`
I initially developed my Django project using SQLite and set the id field of the Company model to UUID. Now that I am migrating the database to PostgreSQL, I need to update the id field to UUID in the PostgreSQL schema.
Details:
1.Current Migration Code:
# Generated by Django 4.2.7 on 2024-04-26 22:25

from django.db import migrations, models
import uuid


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('company', '0002_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='company',
            name='id',
            field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False),
        ),
    ]


2.Migration Error Message:
psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type bigint to uuid
LINE 1: ...ompany_company" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid
                                                              ^


I have attempted to:
Use ALTER COLUMN in the migration file to cast the type, but encountered issues with type coercion.
Add a temporary UUID field and migrate data into it before dropping the original id field, but still faced challenges.

This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464113/django-db-utils-programmingerror-cannot-cast-type-uuid-to-integer
